# Single session using servicestack

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

I like to implement the functionality
where if two users are trying to login with the same credentials then the first user should log out as soon as the second user login.

consider user one is logged in with his credentials from one machine
and  he/ another user is trying to log in from another machine
then the user one session should be removed as soon as user one logged in.

Ps:
I tried to implement that by saving the current session id in the user table and overriding the `OnCreated` method from the `IAuthSession` interface and then checking in that if the request sessionId is the same as the saved session Id if same then process the request else call the lout endpoint.

But It will be not good for performance and I am not sure if it is a good way to do that?

PS: I am using a JWT token.

Update :
I am able to clear the session by using `ICacheClient` to get the session and then remove a session from the server using `IRequest.RemoveSession(sessionId)`, but is it not log out the specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invalidate a user authenticating with stateless authentication like JWT which has the signed authentication embedded in the Token which is valid until the JWT expiry.

i.e. you can't revoke a JWT Token after it's already been issued.

There is a `JwtAuthProvider.ValidateToken` filter you can use to execute custom logic to prevent a user from authenticating which you may be able to use however that would require that you manage a collection of Token info you want to prevent from authenticating before its Token expiry.

Comment: Ok, if I am not wrong you are saying like we have to store all the existing tokens also and then we have invalid the existing token if the user successfully created a new one. right?

Comment: @BhushanDhage You would need to maintain a history of all tokens issued for a user so that when they login your custom `ValidateToken` filter can prevent all tokens for that user to authenticate except the last one.

Comment: Ok i like to know if session_id is unique for sane user, when I login from two different machine. I saw that it is different while debugging but Just want to confirm from you . If it is unique then I can save that latest(last) session_id against that user and I can then check saved session_id against session_id coming from request and using that I can call logout endpoint if the session_id is not matching. Or I will use channel to notify client that session is expired.

Comment: @BhushanDhage sessionId's are irrelevant to the JWT Token, but the ss-id/ss-pid cookies are unique to each users session so you could use it as an identifier however that would require they send a cookie with their JWT Token which goes against the purpose of a stateless auth token, i.e. Client Apps would no longer be able to authenticate with just the JWT Token. Sounds like you'd be better off with normal server sessions so they'd only need the sessionId cookie to authenticate + you can validate if the user is using latest cookie in a Global Request Filter.

Comment: Ok thank you Just last question in the CustomAuthProvider I am not able to use IServerEvents and ICacheClient as it si always null, why is that so?

Comment: @BhushanDhage they're singletons that are configured on the `AuthFeature` not dependencies resolved from the IOC, you can resolve deps from `authService.TryResolve<T>` in your custom auth provider.